# How can I change a tag name in AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Is it possible to change the name of a tag from code?  Something like this:

```
var tag = doc.QuerySelector("i");
tag.TagName = "em";
```

This won't work, because `TagName` is read-only.

But, what are my options for getting to the same end?  Would I have to construct an entirely new tag and set the `InnerHtml` to the contents of the old tag, then delete and swap?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to replace the elements in html string then it can be done this way:

```
 private static string RefineImageElement(string htmlContent)
 {
     var parser = new HtmlParser();
     var document = parser.ParseDocument(htmlContent);

     foreach (var element in document.All)
     {
         if (element.LocalName == "img")
         {
             var newElement = document.CreateElement("v-img");
             newElement.SetAttribute("src", element.Attributes["src"] == null ? "" : 
              element.Attributes["src"].Value);
             newElement.SetAttribute("alt", "Article Image");

             element.Insert(AdjacentPosition.BeforeBegin, newElement.OuterHtml);
             element.Remove();
          }
      }
      return document.FirstElementChild.OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: Note that in new versions of `AngleSharp` `Remove()` and `Insert(...)` methods are gone

Comment: @Abhinandan It is great answer! Could you see this question? [How is it possible to remove all rows from the HTML table using anglesharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784594/how-is-it-possible-to-remove-all-rows-from-the-html-table-using-anglesharp) :)

Answer (score 0):

To change element name, you can replace `OuterHtml` of initial element with combination of :

1. new element opening tag
2. initial element's `InnerHtml`
3. new element closing tag

**Here is an example :**

```
var raw = @"<div>
    <i>foo</i>
</div>";
var parser = new AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse(raw);
var tag = doc.QuerySelector("i");
tag.OuterHtml = $"<em>{tag.InnerHtml}</em>";
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
```

**Output :**

```
<html><head></head><body><div>
    <em>foo</em>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: That's interesting, because it doesn't seem to actually change the tag _in the tag itself_, but will change the tag in the larger body.  If you were to check the `tag.OuterHtml` in that last line, you'd find that it was still surrounded by `I` tags/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question the other day. Later the only solution came to me is simply create another element and copy every attributes from the original element. Then remove the original element.